# nonstandard command line arguments in C#

Tags: c#, cmd, command

So, I've got this command running properly on my PC. I've added it to a directory in the PATH environment variable so that it can be run from anywhere. See normal results:

```
C:\>curl
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

But, when I try to have that command executed in C#:

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe","/K curl");
```

I end up with:

```
'curl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\<project path>\bin\Debug>
```

Is this another noobish mistake? I'm new to C#, making the switch from Java, so thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Type `curl` into that window, if the error is the same the path is not correct

Comment: Do you get this error both within Visual Studio and when you run the .NET program outside of Visual Studio? Did you update PATH while Visual Studio was running?

Comment: @AlexK. I thought that too, but I can even type `cd C:/` and `curl` into the window -- same results, even though I know it can be run from the C:\ directory.

Comment: Also, why don't you start curl directly? Why run cmd and tell it to run curl?

Comment: @MichaelGunter Yes, I do. And no, I didn't. Good thinking though.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen if I do that, I get an error: `The system cannot find the file specified`. Could this be a permissions issue with Visual Studio?

Comment: Nothing to do with VS permissions, that just means the path isn't set up correctly to find curl. You are running everything with the same account when testing manually and from inside the application?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen yep. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had `curl.exe` in C:/Windows/System32. I got around the problem by creating a `C:/curl` directory, adding it to `Path` and putting the executable inside it. Still doesn't work when running it directly, but I can call the command line to do it.

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe","/K curl");
```

Comment: You could add a `CURL_EXE` variable with the full path and `Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/K " + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CURL_EXE") ...);`

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to launch your executable using cmd.exe.

Try launching it directly like the following :

```
Process.Start("curl");
```

Comment: I get an error: `The system cannot find the file specified`. Could this be a permissions issue with Visual Studio?

Comment: Or it could be a Path issue in Visual studio. Does it work at least when starting with absolute curl path (i.e.`Process.Start(@"C:\myDir\curl.exe")` ) ?